# Javascript how `length` is implemented

Tags: javascript

You know that in Javascript you can access the length of an text/array with length property:

```
var obj = ["Robert", "Smith", "John", "Mary", "Susan"];

// obj.length returns 5;
```

I want to know how this is implemented. Does Javascript calculates the length property when it is called? Or it is just a static property which is changed whenever the array is changed. My question is asked due to the following confusion in best-practices with javascript:

```
for(var i = 0; i < obj.length; i++)
{

}
```

**My Problem:** If it is a static property, then accessing the length property in each iteration is nothing to be concerned, but if it is calculated on each iteration, then it cost some memory.

I have read the following definition given by ECMAScript but it doesn't give any clue on how it is implemented. I'm afraid it might give a whole instance of array with the length property calculated in run-time, that if turns out to be true, then the above `for()` is dangerous to memory and instead the following should be used:

```
var count = obj.length;
for(var i = 0; i < count; i++)
{

}
```

Comment: It is not recalculated when referenced, it is set when something happens to change the length of the array. People have been writing `for (var i=0; i<obj.length; i++)` for decades with no "danger to memory". Retrieving length in advance and assigning it to a variable like `count` is merely a micro-optimization that saves one property reference each time through the loop.

Comment: Also, do note that different implementations of JavaScript may have subtly different behavior. In the case of .length, they probably all work how @torazaburo said above, but a precise explanation will be based on the platform.

Comment: @Mostafa: obj.length is 5.

Comment: @Mostafa: Okay, the length is a static property of array, which gets auto updated when you alter it's elements. However, there are a few things to note

Comment: The first version of Microsoft's JScript engine merely held a link list of object members, and hence presumably it took linear time to get the length of an object.

Comment: you can run a cpu profiler in chrome for javascript to see what it calls behind ...anyway while is faster than for in most browsers

Answer (score 5):

Array in JavaScript is not a real Array type but it's an real Object type.

[].length is not being recalculated every time, it is being operated by `++` or `--` operators.

See below example which is behaving same like `array.length` property.

```
var ArrayLike = {
    length: 0,
    push: function(val){
        this[this.length] = val;
        this.length++;
    },
    pop: function(){
        delete this[this.length-1];
        this.length--;
    },
    display: function(){
        for(var i = 0; i < this.length; i++){
            console.log(this[i]);
        }
    }
}

// output
ArrayLike.length // length == 0
ArrayLike.push('value1') // length == 1
ArrayLike.push('value2') // length == 2
ArrayLike.push('value3') // length == 3
ArrayLike.pop() // length == 2
ArrayLike.length === 2 // true
```

Comment: What's a "real Array type"? What a real array is is a matter of perspective only.

Comment: but same implementation is also in c# ...you say that array isn't array after all in all languages(do you think when you speak?)

Comment: @yerforkferchips: in JavaScript array constructor is inherited from Object constructor, like: var somevar = new Array(1, 2, 3, 4);
Now we can use somevar variable to behave like object: somevar.prop1 = "test";
console.log(somevar.length) // 4
console.log(somevar.prop1) // test

Comment: @HellBaby: we can have static properties in JS array
like: somevar.prop1 = "some value", plus JavaScript array does not have a special syntax for creating multidimensional arrays

Comment: Being an Object/having Object in its prototype chain does not make it not an Array.

Answer (score 1):

```
var a = ["abc","def"];

a["pqr"] = "hello";
```

What is a.length?

```
2
```

Why?

a.length is updated only when the index of the array is a numeric value. When you write

```
var a = ["abc","def"];
```

It is internally stored as:

```
a["0"] = "abc"

a["1"] = "def"
```

Note that the indexes are really keys which are strings.

Few more examples:

1.)

```
var a = ["abc","def"];

a["1001"] = "hello";
```

What is a.length?

```
1002
```

2.) Okay, let's try again:

```
var a = ["abc","def"];

a[1001] = "hello";
```

What is a.length?

```
1002
```

Note here, internally array is stored as

```
a["0"] = "abc"

a["1"] = "def"

a["1001"] = "hello"
```

3.) Okay, last one:

```
var a = ["abc"];

a["0"] = "hello";
```

What is a[0]?

```
   "hello"
```

What is a.length?

```
1
```

It's good to know what a.length actually means: Well now you know: a.length is one more than the last numerical key present in the array.

Comment: "Only if the index is a numeric value" is a bit misleading -- anything but numeric property names does *not* behave like indices for arrays, and you certainly won't have these properties come up in any typical loop over an array.

Comment: @yerforkferchips: It is true that the keys which are not numbers won't turn up in a for loop, but a for-in loop would show up. It is always good to know how the length property works, so it doesn't trip us.

Comment: I'm not saying your answer is wrong, but I'm saying what you're showing in that specific example is not array indices, and does not act like them.

Comment: @yerforkferchips Yes, that is right, then again, there is no concept of indices in Javascript. Javascript Arrays are just customized objects, which try to act like a traditional array, providing a bunch of useful helper functions. They are just key-value pairs internally. While, one can use it strictly in the number index format, it is better to be aware of how it works.

Comment: Yes there **is** such a concept: [`Array objects give special treatment to a certain class of property names. A property name P (in the form of a String value) is an array index if and only if ToString(ToUint32(P)) is equal to P and ToUint32(P) is not equal to 232−1.`](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.4). And as I said, your explanation of how length works is fine.

Comment: @yerforkferchips: Thanks, The spec says so. I didn't know that.

Answer (score 0):

> I want to know how this is implemented. Does Javascript calculates the length property when it is called? Or it is just a static property which is changed whenever the array is changed.

Actually, your question cannot be answered in general because all the [ECMA specs](http://www.ecma-international.org/ecma-262/5.1/#sec-15.4.5.2) say is this:

> The length property of this Array object is a data property whose
>   value is always numerically greater than the name of every deletable
>   property whose name is an array index.

In other words, the specs define the invariant condition of the `length` property, but not it's implementation. This means that different JavaScript engines could, in principle, implement different behavior.